# Sending Notification in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

To all
I new for Sending notification 
I didn't know how can register notatification and listen notification .
Can any one help me to explain me in better way with sample  code
How can  register a notification on the button touch of my and then how can I attach a listener for that and when I touch the button then in 
that case the How can listener will hear the notification broadcasted and 
then how will perform the appropriate actions like dropping annotation on map 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Seriously consider cleaning up your language or asking someone better at English to type out your question for you. It'll help others understand you.

Comment: @j.Steen look at the pt2ph8 language

Comment: I see nothing wrong with their language at the moment (granted, they've performed an edit). They're merely telling you to use commas and periods, which you seem somewhat bad at.

Comment: @J.Steen ok But can u help me ?

Answer (score 3):

***To send Notification:***

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"eventName" object:self];
```

***To Receive Notification:***

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(actionMethod) name:@"eventName" object:nil];
```

Comment: @vito how can I register it  For dropping annotation the annotation on the map.I want to drop the annotation on the map by clicking button which is on next page

Comment: I guess the class which has annotations is some different class. 
When that action get performed, send notification! and the interaction is getting done on some view controller class, put receiving notification in viewDidLoad, that will also work.